# Question regarding p-basis in complete local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be the residue field of characteristic $p>0$ of a complete local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $m$. A $p$-basis for $k$ is a subset $B \subset k$ such that

(i) $k^p(B)=k$

(ii) all monomials of the type $b_1^{e_1}b_2^{e_2}.....b_r^{e_r}$ , $b_i \in B$, $0\leq e_i \leq p-1$ are linearly independent.

Now what I can't understand is how can we show existence of this $p$- basis of any field $k$ with $ch k=p>0$, 
because as I think if $k$ is perfect field , then it may not have a $p$-basis. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advanced

Comment: I think $1$ may be chosen to be a basis when $k$ is perfect.

Comment: Yess I couldn't figure it out at first. Sorry that was really stupid of me.

Comment: No worries. I do it all the time. I hope someone else will answer the rest of the existence as I am not familiar with the subject.

Comment: The usual references I see for the existence of a $p$-basis are \[[Nagata](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=460307), (31.2)\] and \[[Matsumura](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139171762), p. 202\]. If you want more details as to how to invoke Zorn's lemma, you can look at \[Stacks, [Tag 07P2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07P2)\]. But feel free to let me know if you need more details!